# How to use forkJoin of Observable with own event

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, reactivex

Im using Subject of reactivex in my angular2 app to signal event.

When I do something like that:

```
let subject1 = new Subject<string>();
let subject2 = new Subject<string>();
subject1.subscribe(data=>console.debug(data));        
subject2.subscribe(data=>console.debug(data));        
subject1.next("this is test event1");
subject2.next("this is test event2");
```

everything works fine, but I want to wait for both events to fire, then do some actions. I found Observable.forkJoin but I cant make it work with Subjects. Code like this dont work

```
Observable.forkJoin(
           subject1.asObservable(),
           subject2.asObservable()
        ).subscribe(
            data => {
              console.debug("THIS IS MY FJ");
              console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error=>console.error(error),
            ()=>{
              console.info('THIS IS MY FJ SUCCESS');
            }
        );
```

Can you help me with this issue please.

Best Regards
Krzysztof Szewczyk

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: @echonax no, nothing, just subscribe method onNext is never called

Comment: As an aside, it isn't working, because you need to call `complete` on the `Subject`s to get an emission from `forkJoin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to use the `zip` operator instead. This operator will merge the specified observable sequences whereas the `forkJoin` one runs all observable sequences in parallel and collect their last elements.

So the `forkJoin` operator is fine with HTTP observables for example but not with subjects.

Here is a sample.

```
export class App {
  subject1: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  subject2: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.subject1.subscribe(data=>console.debug(data));        
    this.subject2.subscribe(data=>console.debug(data));        

    Observable.zip(
      this.subject1,
      this.subject2
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.debug("THIS IS MY FJ");
        console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error=>console.error(error),
      ()=>{
        console.info('THIS IS MY FJ SUCCESS');
      }
  );        
}

test() {
  this.subject1.next("this is test event1");
  this.subject2.next("this is test event2");
}
```

See the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/X74lViYOgcxzb1AjC9dL?p=preview.